# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline keep artifacts for 90 days, or 10 builds worth, which ever i greater

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working with a scripted pipeline for Jenkins, I understand the following will keep builds for 90 days:

```
properties([
    [ $class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', 
        strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '90']],
])
```

and this will keep up to 10 builds:

```
properties([
    [ $class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', 
        strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactsNumToKeep : '10']],
])
```

My intuition tells me that combining them will keep up to 10 builds that are less than 90 days old. What I would like to do is only delete artifacts that are over 90 days when there are more than 10. So the number of builds with artifacts will never drop below 10 even if they are over 90 days

My best guess is the following:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')]),
    [ $class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy:
        [$class: 'EnhancedOldBuildDiscarder', 
            artifactDaysToKeepStr: '90',
            artifactNumToKeepStr: '10',
            holdMaxBuilds: true]],
])
```

Unfortunately I'm new to Jenkinsfiles and don't have any old builds I can experiment with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this setup for a while now, and it does appears to be the correct solution.